# The meaning of wc-rest-dispatcher.xml in Webcommerce

Tags: xml, rest, websphere-commerce

In a Websphere commerce project, I have find a particular file to handle rest calls called *wc-rest-dispatcher.xml* in the folder *com.ibm.commerce.rest*.
It doesn't seems to be a custom files. Searching on the documentation of HCL, however, I can't find any reference to this file.

Anyone knows what this file is used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This file is used to forward the search related request to the Search Server in v8 but not sure if it is still applicable in v9 or later.
There is basic documentation on copyright section of the file.

```
This XML defines routing services related configuration data for REST services.
    
    remoteServerReference: WAS configured name binding for the URL to connect to the remote server.  For example,
                           server or cluster scope: com.ibm.commerce.foundation.server.services.search.url
                           cell scope: cell/persistent/com.ibm.commerce.foundation.server.services.search.url
    forwardHeader: defines whether to include the inbound http header in the outbound request; defaults to true
    forwardQueryString: defines whether to include the inbound query string in the outbound request; defaults to true
    
    inbound: the URI pattern of the inbound request; if matches, the outbound request will be issued instead
    outbound: can be a URI or a fully qualified URL for the outbound request for redirect
    
    Note: - variables can be used in inbound and outbound field - variables at runtime will be transferred "as is"
            to the outbound URI.
          - variables must be enclosed with curly brackets {}.
```